# Templates and URL Structure

Tags: templates, channel, url

EE doesn't allow you to make template groups within groups.

So if you're looking to have "books/chapters/" or "book/chapters/summary" and this didn't happen coincide with channel entries, would the best bet be to use url_segments to simply control with a single template what's  actually displayed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Conditionals based on URL Segments is how I would handle this. For your example, I would have in my books/chapters a conditional like

```
{if segment_2 == "summary"}  
  {embed="embeds/summary_code"}
{/if}
```

I'd use an embed just to keep the template cleaner — instances where I do this do tend to be on more complex site where I like keeping things as clean as possible. It's largely optional and depends on your own coding style.

In that embed, I would then have whatever {exp:channel:entries} code (or whatnot) to output the content I need.

Comment: This would be my approach as well, but I would additionally use IfElse http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/ifelse to reduce page load and deal with advanced conditionals.

Comment: @CreateSean - Thank you too I wasn't aware of that plugin looks very helpful.

Comment: IfElse is simply essential if you are using any advanced conditionals. When I code templates like this, I prefer to use simple conditionals and mostly use advanced ones inside the embed.